# How to set MFMailComposeViewController navigitaion bar backgroundImage at ios 8.3

Tags: ios, iphone

in `AppDelegate` `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`,

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Topbar"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

but when i response system email :

```
 MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
 [mc.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
 [mc.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Topbar"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:^{
         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:NO];}];
```

but `MFMailComposeViewController` also is white

Comment: Use [[UINavigationBar appearance]setBarTintColor:desiredcolor]]

Comment: i don't want to set background color ,i want set MFMailComposeViewController  navbar backbgroundImage ,order to Keep the style is unified

Comment: Well you can't for SDK component. You can get color from image using "+ (UIColor *)colorWithPatternImage:(UIImage *)image" of UIColor but that will lead to a crash when you open MFMailComposeViewController. So better to get a matching color with your image and use above function to set tint color.

Comment: my navigation is no translucent  and I set   backbgroundImage ,if I set setBarTintColor  and then when close MFMailComposeViewController, the app's nav were change,  so what should i  do

Comment: and  I set  [UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[ the color]] when open MFMailComposeViewController the nav still white，why